# javax.swing.Timer inside JDialog does not stop when closing JDialog

Tags: java, swing, timer, jdialog, windowlistener

I have a small application with a main JFrame opening a JDialog as modal. Inside this JDialog I start a javax.swing.Timer that is supposed to stop if the JDialog closes.

```
public Tasks() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    showTasks();

    t = new Timer(10000, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Tasks.this.showTasks();
        }
    });
    t.start();

}
```

But it just keeps running.

I tried to implement WindowListener for the JDialog and I overwrote windowClosed, windowClosing and even windowDeactivated ... to no avail

```
@Override
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Closing");
    t.stop();
}
```

How can I stop the Timer on close of the JDialog?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your approach.

Comment: `opening a JDialog as modal`. Make sure you add the WindowListener to the dialog before making the dialog visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a `WindowListener` to this example, and it seemed to work.

```
this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: +1.. @devnull69 Also if its a `JDialog` use `setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);` :P

Comment: That's it. I just added "implements WindowListener" to the JDialog definition and let Eclipse add the missing methods. This obviously didn't work.

Comment: Easy to omit `addWindowListener`; glad you got it sorted.